# Hobo guy doesnt have Emo gloves in south Park: Stick of Truth

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've been stuck on this for hours, the hobo guy doesn't have the gloves. I've checked every vendor and I definitely didn't sell them. The game is awesome but this is ridiculous.

Comment: The hobo vendor *should* have them as long as you have the quest. Buying the item does not prevent him from selling more. What does your quest marker currently say? Did you get the other 2 pieces?

Comment: You're looking for 'Goth Gloves' not 'Emo Gloves'. Have you checked if the hobo vendor offers Goth Gloves?

Comment: Yeah like @galacticninja sais you need Goth clothes not Emo clothes, Goths will kick your ass if you call them Emo :p

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the quest to 'friend' them first, after you do, the hobo vendor will have the items in his item list (they're clearly marked goth gloves, hat and clothes).